# On the proof of Eisenstein's criterion given in Abstract Algebra by Dummit & Foote

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

My question specifically refers to the proof of Proposition 3 given in chapter 9, section 9.3 of 'Abstract Algebra' by Dummit & Foote. I give the proposition here for convenience:

> Let P be a prime ideal of the integral domain $R$, and let $f(x)$ be a monic polynomial of degree greater than or equal to $1$ in $R[x]$. Suppose, bar the leading coefficient, that the coefficients of $f$ are elements of $P$, and that the constant term of $f$ is not in $P^2$. Then $f$ is irreducible in $R[x]$.

It's assumed, for contradiction, that $f(x)$ is reducible in $R[x]$ so there exists non-zero polynomials $g,h \in R[x]$ such that $f$ is the product of these polynomials. We then reduce this equation $\bmod P$, where $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$. By the assumptions on the coefficients of $f(x)$, one is left with $x^n$ equal to the product of $g$ and $h$ where these polynomials now have coefficients in $(R/P)[x]$. Since $P$ is a prime ideal, $R/P$ is a domain and so it follows that $g$ and $h$ must have $0$ constant term i.e. the constant terms of $g$ and $h$ must both be in $P$. But we also have, in $R[x]$, that the constant term of $f$ is equal to the product of the constant terms of g and h implying that the constant term of $f$ is in $P^2$, a contradiction.

I don't understand why we can assume that both the constant terms of $g$ and $h$ must both be in $P$ by the above argument. Couldn't it be the case that say, for example, the constant term of $g$ was in $P$ but the constant term of $h$ was not. In this case, the constant term of the product of $g$ and $h$ would still be in $P$, but we would not be able to conclude with the contradiction given above.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the proof, as you have conveyed it, is indeed deficient. The proof I give below uses the hypothesis that $f(0)\notin P^2$ in the beginning, instead of D&F’s, which seems to want to use it at the end.

I use the bar notation, as @ArturoMagidin has in his response. Let $n=\deg f$.

We have our two monic polynomials $\bar g$ and $\bar h$ in $(R/P)[x]$, where $R/P$ is a domain. The hypothesis is that one of these (say $\bar g$) has constant term zero, the other, $\bar h$, has nonzero constant. Let us then write $\bar g=x^s\bar g_0$ with $1\le s\le\deg g<n$ and $\bar g_0$ having nonzero constant term. Thus $\bar f=x^s\cdot\bar g_0\bar h$, which has a nonzero $x^s$-coefficient, equal to the product of the nonzero constant terms of $\bar h$ and $\bar g_0$. But this contradicts the hypothesis is that $\bar f=x^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an argument with author approval:

Let $f(x)=x^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_1 x+c_0 \in R[x]$, $R$ an integral domain, $P$ a prime ideal of $R$, where $n\geq 1$ and
$c_{n-1},...,c_1,c_0 \in P$ but $c_0 \not\in P^2$.

Since $n\geq 1$, $f(x)\not=0$.

Suppose $f(x)$ were reducible, then there exist non-units, $a(x),b(x) \in R[x]$, such that $f(x)=a(x)b(x)$ and since $a(x),b(x)$ are not units, if one is constant, then $f(x)\not=a(x)b(x)$ because the leading coefficient on the left is $1$$(f$ monic$)$ whereas the leading coefficient on the right cannot be $1$. Thus $a(x),b(x)$ must be nonconstant polynomials in $R[x]$.

Reducing the coefficients modulo $P$, with the assumptions on the coefficients of $f(x)$

$$x^n = \overline{a(x)b(x)} \in (R/P)[x]$$

Since $P$ is a prime ideal, $R/P$ is an integral domain, and has no zero-divisors, the constant term $a_0b_0$ of $a(x)b(x)$ is $0$ in $R/P$, at least one of $a_0,b_0$ must be $0$ in $R/P$, i.e. at least one of $a_0,b_0$ is in $P$.

Suppose $a_0 \in P$ while $b_0 \not\in P$, then if

$a(x) = a_i x^i + a_{i-1}x^{i-1}+\cdots +a_1 x+a_0, b(x)=b_j x^j+b_{j-1}x^{j-1}+\cdots+b_0$, where $i+j=n$, and $i,j \geq 1$,

there must be some least indexed nonzero constant $a_k \bmod P$, $1\leq k \leq i<n$, otherwise $\overline{a(x)}$ would be identically $0 \bmod P$, and $\overline{a(x)b(x)} = 0 \not= x^n $. But then $a_k\not=0 \bmod P$ and $b_0\not= \bmod P$, so $a_kb_0\not = 0 \bmod P$ since $R/P$ is a domain, and $\overline{a(x)b(x)}$ would have lowest order term $a_kb_0x^k \not= 0\bmod P$  for $k<n$, and cannot be equal to $x^n$. Contradiction. $b_0 \in P$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use an $\overline{\alpha}$ to denote the image of $\alpha\in R$ in the quotient $R/P$.

Because $(R/P)$ is a domain, and you have
$$\overline{a}x^n = \overline{g}\overline{h},$$
then passing the the field of quotients of $R/P$ (and polynomials over fields have unique factorization) we conclude that $\overline{g}$ and $\overline{h}$ must be constant multiples of a power of $x$ in $(R/P)[x]$. That means that if, for example, 
$$g(x) = a_mx^m+\cdots + a_1x+a_0,$$
then reducing modulo $P$ you just get $\overline{g}(x)=\overline{a_m}x^m$. So $a_0,\ldots,a_{m-1}$ must lie in $P$. The same argument holds for $h$. So both the constant terms of $g$ and $h$ must both lie in $P$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm a bit confused about the fifth line of your answer. When you say passing the field of quotients of R/P, could you explain what you're doing? Please correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't it be incorrect to assume R/P a field, as this would require R to be at least a PID.

Comment: @carraig: $R/P$ is a domain, so it has a field of fractions $F$ that contains a copy of $(R/P)$. Therefore, the polynomials in $(R/P)[x]$ can be viewed as polynomials in $F[x]$, just like you can view polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Polynomials in $F[x]$ have unique factorization, so the factorization of $\overline{a}x^n$ is, up to constants, of the form $(\alpha x^i)(\beta x^j)$ with $\alpha,\beta\in F$, $i+j=n$. So, up to a constant in $F$, $\overline{g}$ is a power of $x$, hence it must be of the form $\overline{c}x^i$ for some $c$.

Comment: @carraig: P.S. stackexchange may not display identically in your interface as it does in mine, so it is a bad idea to refer to specific line numbers; rather, you would want to specify specific paragraphs, as those will be respected across platforms. So here, you would want to refer to the statement "after the first display", for example.

Comment: P.P.S. It is incorrect to say that for $R/P$ to be a field we require $R$ to be "at least a PID". The quotient $R/P$ is a field if and only if $P$ is a maximal ideal. But I'm not assuming $R/P$ is a field, just that it is a domain (which holds because $P$ is a prime ideal).

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: Why D&F do or do not do things is something only they can answer; it seems silly of you to be asking *me*. No, $R$ is not interchangeable with its field of fractions. I’m not using Gauss’s Lemma. Gauss’s Lemma tells you that irreducibility over $R$ implies irreducibility over the field of fractions. Here, I am just using factorization over the field of fractions. The information is only going one way, so you don’t need Gauss’s Lemma for anything.

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: No, it’s not. Trust me. I wrote a whole paper about Gauss’s Lemma. Gauss’s Lemma says that a product of primitive polynomials over a UFD $R$ is primitive; as a consequence with some work one deduces that a primitive polynomial with coefficients in a UFD $R$ is irreducible over $R$ if and only if it is irreducible over its field of fractions. Here, we are using that $R$ is **domain**, and that any factorization in $R$ is also a factorization over the field of fractions, and nothing else. You are just wrong.

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: I am not responsible for what you may or may not have seen, and I dispute your claims about it being “alien” compared to D&F, which I am familiar with. This is what we are doing: $f$ is a polynomial over a domain $D$. So it is a polynomial over $F$, its field of fractions. Any factors of $f$ in $D[x]$ are factors in $F[x]$. Since the **only** way to factor $ax^n$ in $F[x]$ is as a product of terms of the form $rx^i$ and $sx^j$, any factorization in $R[x]$ must be of that form. Again, **nothing** to do with Gauss’s Lemma, so you may as well stop invoking it.

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: Gauss’s lemma is a complete red herring here. It has nothing to do with this argument. It is irrelevant.

Comment: @nolemonnomelon Gauss’s Lemma is about UFDs, not arbitrary domains. The only thing being used here is that $F[x]$ is a UFD, so the obvious factorization of $ax^n$ is the *only* factorization: a constant times $n$ copies of $x$. Which is explicit in D&F, as they have already covered that $F[x]$ is a UFD and that $x$ is irreducible. In any case, since your entire line of argument seems to be a complaint about how D&F do things, it has nothing to do with me and is a waste of everybody’s time.

Comment: @nolemonnomelon You aren’t “jumping back” anywhere. The factors were already in $(R/P)[x]$, but they must be of a form admissible in $F[x]$. And again, it seems your complaint is about how D&F do or do not do things, or about what you are able to understand of what D&F say or do not say, or you believe they do not say. Nothing to do with me, so perhaps you should just e-mail them instead.

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: You are **not* “going back down to $(R/P)[x]$.” That is your fundamental misunderstanding of the situation. That is why this has nothing to do with Gauss’s Lemma. You *already have a factorization in $(R/P)[x]$*. You don’t need to go “back” there, *you are already there*. You are only using $F[x]$ to get information about what those factors must look like, but you don’t have to bring “back” anything. *They are already where you want them to be.*